# Group by date to get count of hits for a day, for last 7 days and for a months

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

```
[{'_id': '5ebe39e41e1729d90de',
  'modelId': '5ebe3536c289711579',
  'lastAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 6, 42, 44, 79000),
  'proId': '5ebe3536c2897115793dccfb',
  'genId': '5ebe355ac2897115793dcd04'},
 {'_id': '5ebe3a0d94fcb800fa474310', 
  'modelId': '5ebe3536c289711579',
  'proId': '5ebe3536c2897115793d', 
  'genId': '5ebe355ac2897115793',
  'lastAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 6, 43, 25, 105000)}]
```

I want to calculate count of hits for a day, for last 7 days and for a months. As the model is same, so I want the count of `modelId` based on `lastAt`.

I tried aggregate, group functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure Mongo approach, try the below code:

**Collection:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ebe39e41e1729d90de",
    "modelId": "5ebe3536c289711579",
    "lastAt": ISODate("2020-05-13T06:42:44.000Z"),
    "proId": "5ebe3536c2897115793dccfb",
    "genId": "5ebe355ac2897115793dcd04"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ebe3a0d94fcb800fa474310",
    "modelId": "5ebe3536c289711579",
    "proId": "5ebe3536c2897115793d",
    "genId": "5ebe355ac2897115793",
    "lastAt": ISODate("2020-05-15T12:42:25.000Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ebe3a0d94474310",
    "modelId": "5ebe3536c289711579",
    "proId": "5ebe3536c2897115793d",
    "genId": "5ebe355ac2897115793",
    "lastAt": ISODate("2020-04-19T06:42:25.000Z")
  }
]
```

**Query:**

```js
var now = new Date()
var day1 = new Date(now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1))
var day7 = new Date(now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
var day30 = new Date(now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30))

db.test7.aggregate([
  {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    day: {
      $sum: {
        $cond:[{$and: [{$gt: ['$lastAt', day1]},{$lte: ['$lastAt', now]}]}, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    day7: {
      $sum: {
        $cond:[{$and: [{$gt: ['$lastAt', day7]},{$lte: ['$lastAt', day1]}]}, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    day30: {
      $sum: {
        $cond:[{$and: [{$gt: ['$lastAt', day30]},{$lte: ['$lastAt', day7]}]}, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id:0
    }
  }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "day" : 1, "day7" : 1, "day30" : 1 }
```

**Note:** You can easily convert to PyMongo statements, if you get stuck, please let me know.

Comment: if i've 'count' in the below collections which is in encrypted form, how can i extract the counts for each day                       {
    "_id": "5ebe3a0d94474310",
    "modelId": "5ebe3536c289711579",
    "proId": "5ebe3536c2897115793d",
    "genId": "5ebe355ac2897115793",
    "lastAt": ISODate("2020-04-19T06:42:25.000Z","count" : "AB")
  }

Comment: That goes out of the scope of this question, could you please post another one?

Comment: thanks for reverting the posted with the title " Aggregate function for pymongo and Mongodb for count"

Comment: By any chance , did you look at the post ? @ngShravil.py